# cmake: how to pass extra flags to gcc

Tags: cmake, makefile

I have a project that uses cmake system to compile. I compile the project using

```
cd build
cmake ..  # cmake stage
make      # make stage
```

Sometimes I want to pass an additional flag `-fdiagnostics-json` to gcc in order to easily parse the diagnostic messsages. Normally I compile them without this flag.

I can add/delete it in the `CMakeLists.txt` whenever I want to change the output. The problem is that each time I modify `CMakeLists.txt` I need to restart from `cmake ..` and the whole project is to be rebuilt, including the already built object files.

Is there a way that I can selectively add this flag to gcc during the `make` stage. I tried the following and it seems not working

```
cmake ..

# then
make

# then
make CXXFLAGS="-fdiagnostics-format=json"
```

Answer (score 1):

> I can add/delete it in the CMakeLists.txt whenever I want to change the output. The problem is that each time I modify CMakeLists.txt I need to restart from cmake .. and the whole project is to be rebuilt, including the already built object files.

There is no way of avoiding this. You do change the compiler options after all making all object files out of date, since the the set of compiler options has changed.

You don't need to edit the `CMakeLists.txt` file though. You should be able to pass the compiler option via cmake cache variable without having to modify the cmake files:

Add the option globally for a project set up in directory `build`:

```
cmake -D "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fdiagnostics-format=json" -D "CMAKE_C_FLAGS=-fdiagnostics-format=json" build
```

Reset the options:

```
cmake -U CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -U CMAKE_C_FLAGS build
```

See [`CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html)

---

To set this up for only a single target, you could add a cache variable that can be modified to enable/disable the compiler flags. This should only result in the targets you apply the flags to requiring a rebuild, plus any relinking of binaries linking your target, if any.

```
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
    option(MY_TARGET_ENABLE_DIAGNOSTICS "Add -fdiagnostics-format=json compiler option to my_target" OFF)
    if (MY_TARGET_ENABLE_DIAGNOSTICS)
        target_compile_options(my_target PRIVATE -fdiagnostics-format=json)
    endif()
endif()
```

Enable the option:

```
cmake -D MY_TARGET_ENABLE_DIAGNOSTICS=ON build
```

Disable the option

```
cmake -D MY_TARGET_ENABLE_DIAGNOSTICS=OFF build
```

---

Furthermore a well designed cmake project can be set up in multiple build directories which would allow build files for both versions to exist in parallel.

This requires the cmake project not generating any files in the source tree.

This approach works with both alternatives mentioned above. The commands below assume the second option though.

Initial cmake configuration of a project set up in `src` in `build` and `build_diagnostics`

```
cmake -S src -B build
cmake -D MY_TARGET_ENABLE_DIAGNOSTICS=ON -S src -B build_diagnostics
```

Building both projects

```
cmake --build build
cmake --build build_diagnostics
```

This keeps build files for both alternatives in parallel and should only result in those files being rebuilt, that were modified since the last build on a given directory.

**Note:** With a multi-configuration cmake generator you may even be able to add a separate configuration for the diagnostics option by using generator expressions with `taget_compile_options`. `Unix Makefiles` is not a multi-configuration cmake generator though.

Answer (score -1):

### Disclaimer

It's been criticized that this answer depends on implementation details of CMake and it's true. It also depends on undocumented behavior of CMake. This solution may break with future releases of CMake.

Furthermore, it will only work with the Unix Makefiles generator. However, it does use well-documented behavior of make. Namely the ability to [override variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding.html).

On the pro side, it does offer more flexibility than a clean CMake solution. It's also a one-liner.

If you're still reading, consider this for a one-off run.

### A Q&D one-liner

The flags as used by make are found in the generated build directory in `CMakeFiles/your_project.dir/flags.make`. The variable you're looking for is `CXX_FLAGS` (with an underscore). You could use your favorite text editor to change the flags used by make in place. (Yes, there's a warning not to edit the file, see the disclaimer above.)

Running CMake again will re-generate the file and undo your changes.

You can also pass the variable on the command line. As this will completely override the variable in `flags.make`, you can use sed to read the file and tweak the variable like this

```bash
make "$(sed -n 's/CXX_FLAGS.*/\0 -fdiagnostics-json/p' CMakeFiles/your_project.dir/flags.make)"
```

Comment: Surprised by the downvote without a comment. I verified this is working on my machine. If I misread the question or missed something crucial, I'd be glad to improve my answer based on criticism. I'd be equally happy to see a better answer than mine.

Comment: This may be working but it definetly relies on implementation details of cmake. It's best to avoid hacks like this.

Comment: @fabian thank you for your criticism. I agree with you in principle and a disclaimer to that end would improve my answer. FWIW, the behavior of make is well-documented, here. I'd like to point out, though, that knowing implementation details like this one has saved me hours of work.

Comment: Did a full overhaul of my answer. Vote away.